# update data in an d3 area graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I'm looking for how to dynamically change data in a D3 area graph, like in  [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8).

The only difference, is that i'm using an area graph, like in this code:

```
svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "d3-area")
    .attr("d", area)
    .style('fill', color)
    .transition() // begin animation
        .duration(1000)
        .attrTween('d', function() {
            var interpolator = d3.interpolateArray(startData, data);
            return function (t) {
                return area(interpolator (t));
            }
        });
```

Comment: are you also changing data on `x` axis? or only `y` values?

Comment: both x and y axis

Comment: can you add full working example, so we can modify code?

Comment: I was actually been able to write it on my own (after some a tough learning curve...). thanks!